# Install and invoke Pester remotely

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, azure-devops, pester

I'm new to PowerShell, Pester *and* the new VSO build system and I'm trying to get Pester to run my tests for each check in. I've set up and configured a simple PowerShell script to run on each check in.

[image: PowerShell Configured]

I first tried simply Invoke-Pester to see if the VSO team had envisioned this and set up common unit test frameworks, but I go the following predictable result:

```
Invoke-Pester : The term 'Invoke-Pester' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\a\64df1c11\Operations Tools\powershell\runPowershellTests.ps1:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Pester
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Pester:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to use PSGet:

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
install-module Pester
Invoke-Pester
```

But that isn't working either:

```
New-Item : Access to the path 'PsGet' is denied.
At line:17 char:5
+ New-Item -Path ($Destination + "\PsGet\") -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-N ...
```

How can I remotely install and execute Pester to run my unit tests?

Comment: It looks like any install command needs to be run in admin context, which isn't supported right now.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs

Maybe someone can update this later if something changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with PsGet:

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
Install-Module Pester -Global
```

Or use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/pester):

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install pester
```

Comment: I'll try chocolatey in a sec. This is what I got with a simple install-module:
Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 

At C:\a\64df1c11\Operations Tools\powershell\runPowershellTests.ps1:1 char:1 

+ Install-Module Pester -Global 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: It looks like chocolatey needs to run in admin context, which isn't supported in VSO Build right now (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs)

Chocolatey v0.9.9.8
Installing the following packages:
pester
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
pester v3.3.9
 New-Item : Access to the path 'Pester' is denied.
 At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\pester\chocolateyInstall.ps1:54 char:21
 +             $null = New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction 
... 
The install of pester was NOT successful.

Comment: Same with psget. Oh well, looks like it's not going to work. Thanks for your help.

New-Item : Access to the path 'PsGet' is denied.

At line:17 char:5

+ New-Item -Path ($Destination + "\PsGet\") -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-N ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\syst...\Modules\PsGet\:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAcc 

essException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Answer (score 0):

There is a task in the VSO marketplace that lets you run your Pester unit tests. The task can be found [here at the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts/Build%20and%20release?sortBy=Downloads). You can see the source code at: [git Vsts-Build-Pester](https://github.com/XpiritBV/Xpirit-Vsts-Build-Pester)